# How to make all articles stay together with the~following word?

Tags: formatting

Is there any way to automatically make an~every article to be together with the~next word, and never separated by lines? Something but doing `s/a /a~/g`, `s/an /an~/g` and `s/the /the~/` manually each time, or having a~habit to always type `a~` instead of just `a`

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: Do you require a pdfLaTeX-based solution, or are you open to a LuaLaTeX-based solution?

Comment: @Mico, I would prefer some explaination of LaTeX (or maybe even TeX) innards, those which are related to splitting words by lines, and how to deal with them by altering TeX at the very very low-low-level magic... But I don't limit responses to anything. And here's not just me. Thanks

Comment: (La)TeX has no concept of the meaning of the text it is processing, only of the "categories" of individual characters.  Further, it is a one-way process, so by the time it reaches an "a<space>", it no longer knows what preceded the "a".  Changing the internals to save more context can probably be done with lua, but would undoubtedly slow down processing unacceptably.  There wouldn't be much "public support" for changing the underlying TeX engine

Comment: If you don't mind doing it outside of LaTeX, you could process your input file with a command line tool, perhaps AWK.  The call to AWK and the call to LaTeX could happen sequentially in a batch file.  Presumably, that AWK script would be much simpler to understand and maintain than the LaTeX code.

Comment: @barbara, table of contents, labels and references, tikz "remember picture"... aux, toc,.. It is not one-way process. At least three full building of my book are needed from the scratch, and in fact I'm doing it till there would be no changes in auxiliary files. Is anyone happy having "a || line break || something" in his publications? I bet a solution to this problem has very huge demand

Comment: @VadiqueMyself -- The situations you cite do not demonstrate that this is not a one-way process.  In all those cases, a separate file is written out, and then read in the next iteration.  In *The TeXbook", Knuth recommends using `a~` when it's needed.  Nothing in "default" LaTeX changes that, as you have found.

Comment: You are misunderstanding what Barbara has meant. With "one-way process" she was referring to the way how tex processes files, but not how many compilation steps might be needed.

Answer (score 8):

Here's a LuaLaTeX-based solution. It sets up a Lua function that scans the input at a very early stage for occurrences of (a) `A`, `An`, or `The` followed by one or more space characters and a letter; (b) `a`, `an`, or `the` at the very start of a line, followed by one or more space characters and a letter; and (c) a space character, followed by `a`, `an`, or `the`, followed by one or more space characters and a letter. Whenever a match occurs, the space is replaced with a "tie", i.e., the character `~`.

Note that this setup cannot handle the following case: an article (`a`, `an`, or `the`) occurring at the end of one line and the associated noun occurring at the start of the next line.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luacode}
%% Lua-side code
\begin{luacode}
```

```lua
function auto_tie ( s )
  -- article begins with uppercase letter
  s = s:gsub ( "(The)%s+(%a)"   , "%1~%2" )
  s = s:gsub ( "(An?)%s+(%a)"   , "%1~%2" )
  -- article begins with lowercase letter, at beginning of line
  s = s:gsub ( "^(the)%s+(%a)"  , "%1~%2" )
  s = s:gsub ( "^(an?)%s+(%a)"  , "%1~%2" )
  -- article begins with lowercase letter & is preceded by space
  s = s:gsub ( "%s(the)%s+(%a)" , " %1~%2" )
  s = s:gsub ( "%s(an?)%s+(%a)" , " %1~%2" )  
  return s
end
```

```latex
\end{luacode}
%% LaTeX-side code: assign the Lua function to the 'process_input_buffer'
%% callback, so that it acts as a preprocessor
\AtBeginDocument{\directlua{luatexbase.add_to_callback (
   "process_input_buffer" , auto_tie , "autotie" )}}

\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\setlength\textwidth{1sp} % a rather minuscule line width, force line break whenever possible

\begin{document}
\obeylines% just for this example
A bit
An ant
The stop
\smallskip
a bit
an ant
the stop
\smallskip
  a bit
an ant
 the stop

\medskip
%% no ties in the any of the following cases:
Mega bit
Meghan Anderson
man ant
Berthe stop

\end{document}
```

Comment: Looks reasonable.  What effect does it have on the processing time?  Also, what if "a", "an" or "the" is followed by a control sequence?

Comment: @barbarabeeton - With this code, pattern matches occur only if `a`, `an`, or `the` are followed by (a) one or more space characters ("`%s+`" in Lua-speak) and (b) a letter character ("`%a`" in Lua-speak). Thus, if `a`, `an`, or `the` are followed by space plus a control sequence, no tie (`~`) should get inserted. I have no idea about effect running this function in preprocessor mode may have on processing time.

Comment: Thanks.  I was thinking of the case where a frequently occurring phrase might be represented by a `\cs`; usually, "the", etc., would probably be included, but not if it were also being used as an index term.

Comment: @barbarabeeton - Thanks. I found a 550-page text document with very little LaTeX code in the body of the document -- but a huge number of `a`, `an`, and `the` articles. On my vintage-2013 MacBookPro, the document, primed to be compiled under LuaLaTeX, took about 20.2 seconds to compile without and 20.5 seconds with the additional code proposed in my answer. I guess that's not too bad.

Comment: That really is not too bad!  In fact, much better than I would have guessed.  Good going.