# Preventing text lines to end with a grammatical article (or with short words)

Tags: line-breaking

I am revising a paper before submitting it, and I realized I really dislike when a line ends with an article, and the "articled" word follows on the next line. I found no strict rule for this problem in English, but typographists still recommend avoiding it.

I looked into `\nolinebreak` and `\nobreak` but did not figure out how to apply them automatically throughout the text. I presume there might be a way to check the length of the last word on the line and prevent breaking if it is under four letters of length, which would solve everything, but I could not come up with a solution like that in `LaTeX`.

I am aware of using ~ instead of whitespace between the article and the word, but that seems too laborious.

Comment: this is only really feasible in luatex as otherwise you don't really have access to the words before linebreaking.  In English it's not normally a problem but this seems to a common requirement for certain languages, there are some answers on this site, I'll see if I can find....

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/502266/1090

Comment: In English such a restriction would be very odd, for example in my browser the last words on the line in your question are in almost all cases less than 4 letters (an, in, the, I, too) [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u9cBi.png) and it looks fine to me.

Comment: Thank you for explaining. Could you put these comments into one answer, so I can accept it and close the question? :)

Comment: Why would using `~` be laborious? Should be easy enough to find all occurrences of a/an/the with a regular expression …

Answer (score 1):

This is only really feasible in luatex as otherwise you don't really have access to the words before linebreaking. In English it's not normally a problem but this seems to a common requirement for certain languages.

A related question/answer is:

[How to make all articles stay together with the~following word?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/502266/1090)

In English such a restriction would be very odd, for example in my browser the last words on the line in your question are in almost all cases less than 4 letters (`an`, `in`, `the`, `I`, `too`) and it looks fine to me.

[image: words]